# SQL Server - drop multiple columns with IF EXISTS at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server supports syntax that allows to remove more than one column at a time. [How to DROP multiple columns with a single ALTER TABLE statement in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346120/how-to-drop-multiple-columns-with-a-single-alter-table-statement-in-sql-server)

Though it seems to be impossible to force it to work with `IF EXISTS` clasue for each occurence.

> [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> ```
> DROP
> | COLUMN [ IF EXISTS ]
>       {
>           column_name
>       } [ ,...n ]
> ```
>
> Conditionally drops the column or constraint only if it already exists.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i INT, col1 INT, col2 INT);

ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS col1, col2;
-- col1, col2 were successfully removed

ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS col1,  col2;
-- Msg 4924 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
-- ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'col2' does not exist in table 't'.
```

Based on error message `IF EXISTS` takes effect only for first column.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd40906544cb88c3fc42d020b53c9ae8)**

Is there a limitation of this clause when combined with multiple columns at once?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax is a bit cumbersome but

```
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS col1, 
                   COLUMN IF EXISTS col2;
```

works fine